# Arduino Leonardo based h keyboard

Tags: c++, arduino-leonardo, keyboard

I just want to configure my laptops keyboard buttons <kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>s</kbd>,<kbd>d</kbd>,<kbd>f</kbd>,<kbd>g</kbd>,<kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>j</kbd>. I wrote this code and it works for only <kbd>a</kbd> but I couldn't configure other buttons.

Code is:

```cpp
#include "Keyboard.h"

const int buttonPin = 3;          // input pin for pushbutton
int previousButtonState = HIGH;   // for checking the state of a pushButton
int counter = 0;                  // button push counter

void setup() {
  // make the pushButton pin an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  // initialize control over the keyboard:
  Keyboard.begin();
  Keyboard.press('a');
}

void loop() {
  // read the pushbutton:
  int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  // if the button state has changed,
  if ((buttonState != previousButtonState)
      // and it's currently pressed:
      && (buttonState == HIGH)) {
    // increment the button counter
    counter++;
    // type out a message
    Keyboard.print("a");
  }
  // save the current button state for comparison next time:
  previousButtonState = buttonState;
}
```

How can I configure other buttons <kbd>s</kbd>,<kbd>d</kbd>,<kbd>f</kbd>,<kbd>g</kbd>,<kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>j</kbd> to pin buttons 4,5,6,7,8 and 9.

Thanks for help:)

Comment: You could basically duplicate your code and variables to handle each button, or you could do things with an array or even an object-oriented approach.  6 buttons is about at the point where duplication is unsophisticated, but still practical if it best fits your understanding.  Also you might want to get rid of what looks like a dummy/test 'a' in the setup.